# Where do I submit a feature proposal for MediaWiki GeSHi extension?

Tags: mediawiki, geshi

GeSHi Sourceforge group redirects MediaWiki-related issues to MediaWiki. MediaWiki redirects requests & features back to SourceForge.

I modified my install to parse PHP blocks allowing to highlight HTML/JS/CSS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the MediaWiki extension lives in a directory named `SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi`, and contains a subdirectory `geshi`. If your patch is to the files inside `geshi`, submit the patch to the GeSHi Sourceforge group. If your patch is to the files not in `geshi`, submit it to MediaWiki's bugzilla.

If your patch is to both, hopefully the part of the patch to files inside `geshi` is independently useful. If so, submit that part to the Sourceforge group and the other part to MediaWiki. If the patch to the `geshi` files is *not* independently useful, you may have problems convincing either group to take it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this extension but you can try:

- [MediaWiki's BugZilla](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/)
- [The mailing lists, probably mediawiki-l](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Mailing_lists)
- [The MediaWiki IRC channel on Freenode](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/mediawiki)